# QEMU-KVM: Can't virtualize in nested hypervisor with error: ERROR Host does not support any virtualization options

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, linux-kvm, hypervisor

I have a qemu-kvm hypervisor in Ubuntu (Level 0) with a CentOS 7 as a VM (Level 1), which I also installed QEMU-KVM, turning it into another hypervisor, where I intend to have Arch as a VM (Level 2). My CentOS 7 (Level 1) seems to be working fine.

I activated nested virtualization in my Hypervisor (Level 0):

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf
options kvm_intel nested=1

$ cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested
Y
```

Inside my CentOS VM (Level 1) I confirmed KVM is present:

```
# echo "Number of processors that support KVM: $(grep -Ec "(vmx|svm)" /proc/cpuinfo)"
Number of processors that support KVM: 2

# lscpu | grep "Virtualization\|Hypervisor"
Virtualization:        VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full

# lsmod | grep -i kvm
kvm_intel             170181  0 
kvm                   554609  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              13503  1 kvm
```

Now when I try to install my Arch in my CentOS Hypervisor (Level 1) it fails. Below, you'll see that even the option `--prompt` fails:

```
# virt-install --name=Nested-Arch --vcpus=1 --ram=512 --os-type=linux --os-variant=virtio26 --nographics --description "Arch Linux inside CentOS inside Ubuntu (Nesting)" --network bridge=virbr0,model=virtio --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/guest.img,size=32 --cdrom=/root/Downloads/archlinux-2016.09.03-dual.iso --extra-args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial"
ERROR    Host does not support any virtualization options

# virt-install --prompt
WARNING  --prompt mode is no longer supported.
ERROR    Host does not support any virtualization options
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at libvirt logs (journalctl -xeu libvirtd) I found out this error every time I was trying to use virt-install:

> Abr 21 15:10:25 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[2156]: 2019-04-21
>   19:10:25.351+0000: 2176: error : virQEMUCapsNewForBinaryInternal:4589
>   : internal error: Failed to probe QEMU binary with QMP:
>   /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm: relocation error: /lib64/libspice-server.so.1:
>   symbol SSL_CONF_CTX_set_ssl_ctx, version libssl.so.10 not defined in
>   file libssl.so.10 with link time reference

A quick search led me to this [RHEL page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1627693). Basically it said there is a bug with older versions of openssl and qemu. My openssl was 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 and I updated to openssl-1.0.2k. Now it works like a charm.